url_launcher while using flutter_local_notification
please, am using flutter_local_notification as a reminder solution in my app, and my notifications have actions of which one of the actions involes using url_launcher. Other actions work well,but the action with url_launcher does not. Going through the documentation i saw this "Developers should also note that whilst accessing plugins will work, on Android there is no access to the Activity context. This means some plugins (like url_launcher) will require additional flags to start the main Activity again.", could someone please elaborate more, and is it the cause of it not working. this is specific for when i tap on the notification from the background, that is the app is termited and onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse callback is called
this is a sample of the url_launcher when the action is pressed
final Uri url = Uri(
                  scheme: "tel",
                  path: phoneNumber,
                );
                if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
                  await launchUrl(url);
                } else {
                  log("could not launch url to callnnumber: ${phoneNumber}");
                }

this is the action :
 AndroidNotificationAction(
            callActionId,
            "call",
            showsUserInterface: true,
          
          ),

